# Is there a Monotouch Color Picker control?

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog, color-picker

I see a whole bunch of iOS open source common controls to pick a color, but I've not found anything that I can use for Monotouch in C#. I've looked in Monotouch.Dialog but can't see it.

Here's some iOS one's I've found:

http://maniacdev.com/2011/11/open-source-ios-color-picker-components-roundup/

Has anyone got anything like this, or could provide some advice?

Comment: if you have source, you could either convert it to C#, or write MT bindings for it

Comment: Do people just manually convert the C# (it does looks similar, but my ObjC-fu is low, hence using C#)? Also, any more info on how to do a binding i.e. between MT and a run-time library I could make out of one of these please?

Comment: Yes, converting to C# might be easiest, particularly for fairly small project.  Binding is covered here: http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_types

Comment: I agree with @Jason that porting the source is the way to go. Bindings are useful for large ObjC codebases like TestFlightSDK but I wouldn't split user interface (and color picker is UI) across ObjC and C#. Also, you'll learn a great deal about UIKit and ObjC just by porting the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it is some time from when you posted your request, but I also needed a color picker for monotouch, so I developed one and I would like to share the code with anyone interested.

You can find it on github: http://yiannisbourkelis.github.com/AdvancedColorPicker/

It is a very simple and easy to use component and you can use it in any free or commercial application.

Comment: This looks awesome. I do feel like it is overkill for what I want it for, but thats why we take what we need and change the rest.